# Proper LINQ Expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-expressions

I've been trying to search Google but to no avail. It feels like it's been asked before, but maybe I'm not Googling what I think I need correctly.

I want to get a collection of `Object` who's `ICollection<T>`'s `Id` property is a `value`.

Which way should I write this Linq Expressions?

For example:

```
public class User {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class UserRole {
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
}
```

If I know a `RoleId`, how do I get all the `User`'s? The following seems like it's correct and it does give me what I need:

**Example 1**

```
var roleId = 1;
var users = db.UserRoles.SingleOrDefault(r => r.RoleId == roleId).Roles;
```

**but**, is it possible to get the same results in reverse? For example, I've tried this:

**Example 2**

```
var roleId = 1;
var users = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserRoles.Where(r => r.RoleId == roleId)).Users;
```

I get a message saying `Cannot convert type UserRole to bool`.

- Are there any other ways to get the `Users`?
- Knowing that I want `Object-X`, but only knowing a value from a `Navigation` property, how should I be thinking to write the expression?

  - Should I be thinking: "Get `Object-Y where It's Id is this, then give me Object-X`"
  - or something else?

I ask because I'm using to thinking like this: "Get `Object-X where it's Object-Y has this value".

Maybe I'm making this confusing, but I hope someone helps clear it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I know a RoleId, how do I get all the User's?

Assuming **Role** class has a **RoleId** property you can do something like that:

```
var roleId = 1;
var users = db.Users.Where(q => q.Roles.Any(w => w.RoleId == roleId));
```

Comment: Ah! That's what I was missing! I need to remember that `Any()`